# SQL Distict Count from mulitple columns in multiple database

Tags: sql, count, distinct

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT p2.fullname[UploadedBy], p.fullname[UploadedTo]
from docexchange d (NOLOCK)

left join exchange_permissions r on r.file_id = d.id
inner join people p on r.people_id = p.id
inner join people p2 on d.upload_by_id = p2.id

where upload_date > '2013-05-21'
```

This query returns about 8000 results -- if I add `DISTINCT` to my `SELECT` statement it returns about 900 results -- I want to get those 900 results but I need another column that tells me how many times those results showed up in the database.

I've tried do this:

```
Select p2.fullname, p.fullname, COUNT(DISTINCT p2.fullname + p.fullname)
```

but that returns an error: Column 'people.fullname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `group by`:

```
SELECT p2.fullname as [UploadedBy], p.fullname as [UploadedTo], count(*)
from docexchange d (NOLOCK)

left join exchange_permissions r on r.file_id = d.id
inner join people p on r.people_id = p.id
inner join people p2 on d.upload_by_id = p2.id

where upload_date > '2013-05-21'
group by p2.fullname, p.fullname
```

Comment: Awesome thanks -- 9 minutes until I can accept this as the answer.  Totally a novice in SQL. Thanks again!